# Can we write a regex to accept all the duplicate '.' that is decimal points in a string?

Tags: regex, regex-negation, regexp-replace

I want to **accept** all the decimal points, just the decimal points in the string except the first one.
For example-
1.2 should be **rejected** but in 1..2 or 1.2.3, all the decimals after the first one should be accepted by the regex

Comment: What is your end goal here?

Comment: Actually, I am using the .replace() function in JS to replace the characters that are accepted by the regex as the first argument of .replace(). So I want to accept all the duplicate decimals in the regex so that they can be replaced with the empty string("") with the help of str.replace('regex', ''), so that after using the replace function, 1..2 or 1....2 becomes 1.2 and 1.2.3 or 1..2.3.4 becomes 1.234

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can try the following regex approach using a callback function:

```js
var input = "1..2.3.4";
var output = input.replace(/^(.*?\.)(.*)$/g, (x, y, z) => y + z.replace(/\./g, ""));
console.log(output);
```

The logic here is to match the first portion of the input string up to, and including, the very first dot, in the first capture group.  Then, in the second capture group, we match the remainder of the string and we strip all dots from this component.

Comment: The output from this code is 1.2.3.4 but the expected output is 1.234. Basically, all the decimals should be replaced with the empty string except the first one

Comment: No, the output from this code is `1.234`.  Run the demo again.

Comment: Yes now its correct, thanks